North pole continent: effects on climate
As the title implies, this question is straight forward: how would the climate develop if an Antarctica-like continent had developed during, say, the pleistocene? Would winters be milder in the northern hemisphere, like they are in the southern one? Would the climate be dryer?
Thanks for your time.

Firstly, I will assume that this north polar continent roughly covers the size of the northern sea ice in winter:

Given that the North Pole lacks a circumpolar current like the Antarctic Circumpolar Current, the climate of this Arctic continent would likely be warmer and more seasonal, probably resembling eastern Siberia moreso than Antarctica.
North Western Europe would be a bit drier, but otherwise not affected that much.
That is, if you use a climate similar to today’s climate as your starting point.
However, since this continent you described existed from the Pleistocene, and assuming the Last Glacial Maximum still occurs in this alternate Earth, the ice age would likely still grip Northern Europe under kilometres of ice thanks to large cold air masses descending from the glaciated Arctic continent to the south. In this case, the climate of the whole world (but particularly the northern hemisphere), would be much drier AND colder. Evaporation would be lower, both cold deserts and tundra would extend much further than even our world’s ice age cold deserts/tundra did.
